# Getting class of lateinit property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it somehow possible to get `::class.java` from Kotlin `lateinit` property before it is initialized?

Logically it should work - I'm trying to obtain a class not a value, but in reality it fails with uninitialized property access exception.

Note that the property I'm trying to get class of is in generic class and its type is one of generic parameters:

```
abstract class MVIFragment<
        out INTERACTOR : MVIInteractor<UINTERFACE>,
        UINTERFACE : MVIUIInterface,
        MODEL : MVIViewModel
        >
    : Fragment(), MVIUIInterface, KodeinAware {


lateinit var viewModel: MODEL
```

I need the class to create an instance of `ViewModel`

```
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(viewModel::class.java)
```

Of course I can't do:

```
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MODEL::class.java)
```

Any solution for that?

Comment: Have you try reflection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to type erasure, generic types are not known at runtime. That's just how Java/JVM works, and Kotlin doesn't attempt to magically work around it. (Unlike Scala, which has implicit magic which works magically, except when it doesn't.)

You will have to pass it along from some context where the type is statically determined, e.g.

```
class Container<T : Any>(private val tClass: Class<T>) {
    val t: T = tClass.newInstance()
}

Container(String::class.java)
```

You can use an inline function with reified types to hide this ugliness,

```
class Container<T : Any>(private val tClass: Class<T>) {
    val t: T = tClass.newInstance()

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <reified T : Any> invoke() = Container(T::class.java)
    }
}

Container<String>()
```

which really compiles to the same thing. (The `<String>` can be omitted if type inference can determine it from context.)

In your case, it won't be possible to do this trick in the base (abstract) class; it has to be done on the concrete types.